# Unselectable when z-index is less than zero

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm wondering as to why I failed to select and de-select the element when its z-index is less than zero (append selected to div class)?

```
function selectedElement(eventName) {
    eventName.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.target.classList.toggle("selected");
    });
}
```

I have another function that increase or decrease the z-index by 1. As long as the z-index is zero or greater I can select or de-select the element but as soon as the z-index hits bellow zero then I can no longer toggle selected.

What is the reason for this?

Edit 1: Include HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Javascript 1</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box1" class="box center green size200"></div>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's probably becsuse another element covers it. Could you include HTML as well?

Comment: @FZs Included HTML per request

Comment: Could the div get behind the body tag that's why it cannot be seleted?

Comment: Edit your post and use the "insert snippet" button to add the full html, css and javascript so we can run it